# How rule matching in iptables work?

Tags: iptables

Hi I have two rule in my iptables

Rule 1
destination IP 10.0.0.0/16 block all

Rule 2
destination IP 10.0.0.0/24 allow tcp

So the subnet mask overlap in a certain range.
So if a packet comes with destination IP 10.0.0.1 does it allow or deny.?

Answer (score 0):

This simply depends on the order of your rules. They are tested from top to bottom. If a rule matches and accepts or declines, then the process is stopped.

So you need to code exceptions first, then more general rules.